# Why does Commander Shepard never call in a tactical airstrike?

Tags: mass-effect

I've been replaying *Mass Effect* lately, and I recently noticed something: 
 Commander Shepard is a naval officer in charge of a (presumably armed) warship.

This is significant because there are a lot of surface missions where the obvious solution to fights where the Mako is outgunned is "radio Joker and have the *Normandy* bomb/strafe the crap out of the [Geth base/thresher maw/mercenary camp/whatever]."  And yet he never does.  Here he is, with what everyone keeps calling one of the most advanced ships in the fleet... and he treats it as nothing more than a bus.

Comment: Voting to leave open. Seems to be on-topic as per: [Should lore questions as an entire category be banned?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7696/4797)
[When is it appropriate to close a lore question as “not addressed directly through in-universe sources”?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7673/4797)
[Is “This question requires developer only knowledge” the same thing as developer intent?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9901/4797)
[Do we close plot-explanation questions if the answer is 'there is no explanation'?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8473/4797)

Comment: Also relevant: [On questions of developer intent, and the routing around thereof](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7385/on-questions-of-developer-intent-and-the-routing-around-thereof).  Asking if the developers have ever talked about anything is developer intent, and off-topic.  This would likely be on-topic with just the last line removed.

Comment: A lot of the time the Fith Fleet calls you because it's an infiltration/recovery mission and they specifically say they don't want to bomb it from orbit.

Answer (score 8):

There is no official statement as to why *Normandy* is not used for strikes, but here it is probably related to the fact that strikes by starship guns tend to level the entire area. Quite often, enemies are located in areas that you want to enter or otherwise not to destroy.

That is the first part, related to firepower.
The second is related to the nature of *Normandy*:

***Normandy* is a stealth vessel**, a submarine in space if you will. It is not a strike craft. While *Normandy* can hide itself in space, for a limited amount of time, it can be seen from a planet's surface where anti-starship guns can target it. Furthermore, since the ME fields needs to be generated to allow the ship to fly in gravity fields, its shields are weak. In one of the ME books (I forgot which), a frigate was destroyed by a shoulder launched anti-ship missile launcher in the atmosphere.

Often, the *Normandy* operates in areas that the enemy is heavily entrenched in and as a result, trying to approach these areas for high-precision attacks, is far more risky than just taking the site on foot. For example, on Feros, trying to attack the Geth dropship would have had every Geth gun target *Normandy*, which is not build for extended combat.

Talking with Anderson and Presley, they will tell you that *Normandy* is ideal for stealthy insertions rather than combat. In other words, being a "bus". **It has teeth, but it should only bare those as a last resort**. Its primary method of dealing with enemies is to hide and run, not stand and fight.
This is best seen in the opening of *Mass Effect 2*: the moment the *Normandy* is noticed by the Collectors and it fails to hide and run, it suffers catastrophic damage.

Comment: Perhaps the weapons don't even work properly in [different] atmospheres? I seem to remember ME1 has some pretty harsh environments that you land the MAKO in (death in 10 seconds?) - perhaps the Normandy can only tolerate these briefly?

Comment: I don't issue is atmosphere. If Mako can survive them, then Normandy should be more than capable of handling them. There was no mention of atmospheric conditions limitations for Normandy anywhere. Furthermore, the gun is a mass accelerator: it simply "throws" a solid slug at extreme speeds. It should not be affected by the atmosphere that much, unlike GARDIAN lasers.

Comment: @Mandemo I highlighted parts of your answer (I like that second sentence, +1 :) as I edited it. If you disagree, you can change it, naturally.

Comment: I'm not sure that example really applies.  It's been a while since I played 2, but I seem to recall that the reason the *Normandy* got beaten was not that it got in a fight *per se*, but that it got in a fight with a ship much bigger than itself.  (And armed with Reaper weapons tech to boot!)

Comment: It is true that Collector vessel carriers a massive particle beam weapon, but as can been over ME2 with the Normandy SR-2, a sufficiently armed ship can deal with it and take a blow (at least one). SR-1 had none of the upgrades and the beam acted like the barrier wasn't even there